# Travis-ci: Watch and build a single branch from a Git remote repository

Tags: git, validation, git-branch, travis-ci

I am actually envountering some issues with Travis-CI.
Let's say that I have a repository on Github, with multiple branches.
I just need to validate and build the **master branch**, and ignore any other branches.
Looking at Travis docs, it seems I have to push a single `.travis.yml` file in every single branch of my repository. But should all these yml files have the same contents ?
In other words, [do I have to have this](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Specify-branches-to-build) at the top of each single travis.yml file in every branches:

## In every single yml file

```
branches:
  only:
    - master
```

In my yml file, I wish to run a script that runs specs tests, in the master branch, that validates the build with travis. Those specification tests are written in files that only exist in the master branch, not the others, as I don't need them there. So, I guess I'll also have to skip the script part in the yml file pushed in every branch different than the master ? As follows:

```
#YAML file (master branch)
branches:
  only:
    - master

# run the script
script: "tsc -f specs/*"
```

In some other branch:

```
#YAML file (any other branch)
branches:
  only:
    - master
```

Thanks reading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>Yes, you currently have to specify the build-branches in the `.travis.yml` for every branch.</s>

No, the script line does not have to be included in every branch's file.

<s>**Edit**: You might also be interested in observing [this feature request](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/902) for travis-ci.</s>

**Update**: Since March 2014, you can disable building for branches/commits without a `.travis.yml` file in the repository settings on travis-ci.org. The option is (currently) called "Build only commits with .travis.yml file", see also [this blog post](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-03-05-repository-settings/)

Comment: Thanks Nevik, that all worked fine, thanks. I messed with that yesterday, and it kept failing to build the master branch, but I guess it maybe related to some error syntax in my travis YAML files. Thanks for the link, i'll also mention this [pull request](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/414) I ran into yesterday, while searching.

Comment: Thanks, @RolandY., that looks useful. I'll keep an eye on that as well :)